# sound stopped working Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, audio, speakers, ubuntu-18.04, clicking-sound

I was using my laptop all afternoon with no issues, now there is no sound coming from either the built-in speakers or headphones when plugged in. I didn't re-start the system before the problem started. I'm running Ubuntu 18.04, and have been for some time. I have tried usual error tests:

- Sound card is recognized by the system
- Made sure pavucontrol is set to "Analog stereo duplex"
- Use alsamixer to ensure that nothing is muted

I have tried running

```
sudo alsa force-reload
```

As well as

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base
sudo apt-get remove --purge pulseaudio
sudo apt-get install alsa-base
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio
sudo alsa force-reload
```

Using `speaker-test` sound is made through the headphones but not through the built in speakers.

Every time I restart, or plug in headphones, the built in speakers click. This also happens when I mute/un-mute the sound usnig keyboard shortcut.

When I run `aplay -l` I get:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC3266 Analog [ALC3266 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Any thoughts appreciated, thanks

Comment: After doing one more `sudo alsa force-reload` and a re-start (out of hope), the clicking has stopped, and the built in speakers now produce sound with `speaker-test`

Comment: I've also just noticed that the speakers make the usual sound when the power is plugged and unplugged